# Significato di "addebito" in questo articolo giornalistico

Tags: word-meaning

Su questa [notizia di Euronews](https://it.euronews.com/2020/11/10/la-commissione-ue-accusa-amazon-abusa-dei-dati-di-societa-terze) ho letto (grassetto mio):

> Commissione europea ha accusato la multinazionale americana di vendite Amazon di abusare dei dati ottenuti da altre società che utilizzano la piattaforma per vendere i propri prodotti. Bruxelles ha formalizzato questa accusa inviando una comunicazione degli **addebiti** alla società.

Ho ricercato il significato di "addebito" sul [vocabolario Treccani](https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/addebito) e sul [*Grande dizionario della lingua italiana*](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI01/00000157.jpg), ma non riesco a capire che senso ha questo termine nel contesto dell'articolo sopra citato. Qualcuno di voi saprebbe spiegarlo?

Comment: È il significato 2 in entrambi i dizionari, gli hanno comunicato di cosa sono accusati

Comment: @OldManofAran:    Quindi, "gli addebiti" sarebbero le colpe, i danni, i misfatti commessi da Amazon (e che, con questa comunicazione, si attribuiscono ad Amazon)?

Comment: @Charo - sì, debito nel senso di quanto viene “addebitato” (di cui si chiede conto) ad Amazon. ***Addebitare:*** 2. fig. Attribuire, addossare una colpa a qualcuno: gli addebitarono tutta la responsabilità dell’accaduto. https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/addebitare/

Comment: @Hachi:  Cioè, si tratterebbe di tutte le colpe attribuite ad Amazon, no?

Comment: Più che colpe, sono accuse vere e proprie con possibili implicazioni legali.

Comment: Ogni volta che leggo qualcosa in italiano che viene da Euronews mi sembra scritto da un extraterrestre che ha imparato molto bene l'italiano ma non ha mai parlato con un italiano né letto un vero testo in italiano.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Con **addebiti** nel testo proposto si intendono evidentemente le accuse che sono state formalizzate dalla Commissione Europea e comunicate ad Amazon, quindi siamo nell'ambito del significato 2 di entrambi i dizionari citati, come è già stato notato nei commenti.

D'altro canto è inverosimile che "addebiti" possa essere qui inteso nel senso del significato 1 dei dizionari dal momento che l'eventuale addebito in senso *pecuniario* potrebbe essere definito solo contestualmente ad una sentenza o ad un accordo tra le parti (nel qual caso probabilmente non verrebbe usato "addebito" bensì qualcosa come "corrispettivo pattuito"), entrambe occorrenze che verosimilmente non sono già intervenute dal momento che sono appena state formulate le accuse.

Comment: Benvenuto su Italian.SE e grazie della risposta!

Comment: @Charo Grazie a te e bentrovata! :-D